# Open with - no "use always" option on some extensions

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm trying to assign my preferred video player for the video files, and for some extensions I can set the "always use this app" no problem, but for some extensions - for instance mkv - it shows the "open with" window, but no "use always" option there. Any known way to fix it in a better way than the "defaults" in control panel?

Comment: Did you try changing it from Settings -> Default applications -> Default applications by file types?

Comment: @BlindSpots it's VLC, if you think that it matters. Not sure what you mean. Windows doesn't let applications manage extensions anymore.

Comment: @BlindSpots "Next, select VLC media player from the available options and then check “Always use this app to open .mp4 files.” and click “OK“". - and this, as I wrote, doesn't work properly.

Comment: @BlindSpots and this, as I wrote, is a way that I already know but it's very cumbersome. And, in theory, it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

#### Registry Edit

The solution below requires editing the Windows registry.

#### Warning about Registry Edits

Standard registry edit warning provided by Microsoft:

> **Warning:** Exercise extreme caution when using the Registry Editor. If you edit the registry incorrectly, serious problems might occur that could require a complete reinstall of the operating system and result in data loss. Avoid any edits suggested by unofficial sources.  For added protection, before making edits based on officially published Microsoft documentation, be sure to back up the registry. Then you can restore it if a problem occurs. For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692).

#### Instructions

This registry edit will restore the **"Always use this app to open..."** option to the **"How do you want to open this file"** dialog if it is missing.

1. You must be signed in as a user with administrator privileges
2. Save the code that follows to a text file with a `.reg` extension or [download this file](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/278126d1589128129-how-add-remove-open-always-use-app-windows-10-a-add_always_use_this_app_to_open.reg) from TenForums

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\OpenWithSetDefaultOn]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\OpenWithSetDefaultOn]
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"
"ProgrammaticAccessOnly"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\OpenWithSetDefaultOn\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4f,00,70,00,\
  65,00,6e,00,57,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2d,00,6f,\
  00,76,00,65,00,72,00,72,00,69,00,64,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,\
  00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{e44e9428-bdbc-4987-a099-40dc8fd255e7}"
```

3. Merge `.reg` file with your system registry by double-clicking it.
4. To approve the merge, when prompted:

   1. click <kbd>Run</kbd>
   2. then <kbd>Yes</kbd>
   3. then <kbd>Yes</kbd> again
   4. and finally <kbd>OK</kbd>

- **Source:** [Windows TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/156072-how-add-remove-open-always-use-app-windows-10-a.html)